# Remove back button in ModernUI plugin for wpf

Tags: wpf, themes, back, modern-ui

I am trying to develop a modern wpf application using the MUI package. However I do not wish for the back button to be present and I tried to follow the steps mentioned in [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3789b7/modern-ui-for-wpf-application-by-example-default-window-wit/) link but it is not working.

I am getting errors as controls not defined in namespace, etc. Basically, I cannot get the code to compile. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `TargetType` property in the `Style` references controls from the ModernUI library, you need to add the XML namespace for the ModernUI controls in the `ResourceDictionary` containing the `Style`.

I don't know what that namespace is, but need to add something like this:

```
xmlns:mui="clr-namespace:FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Controls;assembly=FirstFloor.ModernUI"
```

Comment: Hi Glen. Thanks for your reply. I did that too but it shows ModernWindow does not exist in that namespace.

Comment: And if just comment out the back button code and leave the rest as is, the Initialize component funtion in MainWindow.xaml.cs is undefined

Comment: Like I said in my answer, I do not know the exact namespace as I do not have the Modern UI library to hand, you would need to find out what it is.

Comment: Went down this path, had to make a few edits to those files but had it working :)

Comment: This seems to be a common issue. As Glen already suggested, "assembly=FirstFloor.ModernUI" is required to be added to the namspace. More details can be find at: https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/issues/53