# How to hide column sorting box from DataGrid in Modern UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, modern-ui

I'm using [First Floor Software's Modern UI for WPF Templates](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7a4362a7-fe5d-4f9d-bc7b-0c0dc272fe31).

I disabled the option to sort the columns, both for the entire DataGrid and for each column using these:

```
CanUserSortColumns="False"   <-- in the .xaml
CanUserSort = False          <-- in the .xaml.cs
```

It does disable sorting, but the box in which the sorting arrow would go is still showing up and blocking the header text:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSRQb.png (I can't post the image yet)

Columns are `FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn`.

In this picture, you can see that at this width, about half of the header is blocked by the sorting box. I would like to remove this box.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the resource directory from the original project which contains the style for the DataGridTextColumn to your Application and than you can maintain it. It is similiar to this [removing back button in modern ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105137/remove-back-button-in-modernui-plugin-for-wpf) post.